# reading large chunks of data from CCM nodes from python script leads to nodes getting shut down

Tags: cassandra, ccm

I have a CCM cluster of 3 nodes. I am writing and reading data to it through a python script. I can write all the data (small or large) easily. When I am reading large chunks of data from a python script, the nodes get shut down. When trying it from CQLSH I can read any amount of data successfully. I am including the error message below.

```
temp = session.execute("""SELECT * FROM ***.***""")

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/divyansh/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "<ipython-input-2-fccba5094f88>", line 2, in <module>
SELECT * FROM ***.***""")
File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 2240, in 
cassandra.cluster.Session.execute
File "cassandra/cluster.py", line 4198, in 
cassandra.cluster.ResponseFuture.result
cassandra.cluster.NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to complete the 
operation against any hosts', {<Host: 127.0.0.1:9042 datacenter1>: 
ConnectionShutdown('Connection to 127.0.0.1:9042 was closed',)})
```

Comment: Could you share the Table schema?

Comment: CREATE TABLE powertrain.mytable (
    rowkey text,
    channel text,
    unit text,
    comment text,
    samples text,
    timestamp text,
    PRIMARY KEY (rowkey, channel, unit)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (channel ASC, unit ASC)

Comment: Both samples and timestamp are lists of numbers. While others are just small strings.